# Opening the Gallery in Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that allows you to open a picture from the gallery. When you add a picture fromt he gallery to the app, it records the URI and then uses that URI to open the picture again when you want to.

This has been working fine on Honeycomb and ICS, but on Jellybean (4.1) I always get the first picture n the album opened in the gallery.

I have double checked that the URI is in fact changing when I make the call to the gallery.

Here's the code that opens the gallery

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

And here's the URI...

```
content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5477659987595757282
```

Again, this is the URI that is provided form the gallery when the picture is initially selected, so the URI "should" be fine, and this is a Jellybean only issue, I'm even running on the same device that was running ICS and it used to work fine. Now it opens the correct album, but always shows the first picture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is specifically, but what I do know is that you are making use of the internal APIs... you shouldn't do that. OEMs (i.e. Samsung, HTC, etc.) might potentially change these URIs in the future, causing old apps to break on new devices. More specifically, you aren't guaranteed that the URI you've posted will stay consistent as new versions of Android are released (since it isn't part of the public API).

At the very least you should check to see if the package associated with the given uri exists using the `PackageManager` (and if it doesn't, prompt the user with a toast warning them that the action can't be completed).